# After executing incrementing thread, variable is always the same

Tags: java, multithreading

Im trying to understand threads. 
I wrote simple program.

```java
public class Main {
    static int counter = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Thread t1 = new Thread(() -> {
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
                counter++;
            }
        });
        Thread t2 = new Thread(() -> {
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
                counter++;
            }
        });

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t1.join();
        t2.join();
        System.out.println(counter);
    }
}
```

The result is always 2000, but I do not know understand why. Any of the run methods are not synchronized so why it is giving me always the same result.

If I write:

```
 t1.start();
        t1.join();
        System.out.println(counter);
        t2.start();
        System.out.println(counter);
```

then I got result: 1000,1000. Why it is always equals to 1000?

Comment: *The result is always 2000, but I do not know understand why* - pure luck, nothing more. I immediately got a result lower than 2000 on the very first run on java-12.

Comment: @Eugene I always had 2000, that's why I was asking :P

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your loops are so short that `t1` finishes before `t2` gets going.  Try 100,000 instead. Lack of synchronization does not guarantee you will have concurrency issues but correctly incorporating synchronization will prevent them.

Answer (score 5):

> The result is always 2000, but I do not know understand why.

because you were lucky enough to not have any race condition between the two threads. Just because a race condition *can* happen doesn't mean that it's *guaranteed* to happen.

> Why it is always equals to 1000?

Because the second thread has not executed yet when you print the counter for the second time. Or because it has executed, but since there is no visibilty guarantee due to the lack of synchronization, the main thread can still see the latest value.